# Is it safe to use firebase admin SDK with next.js 13 server actions?

Tags: firebase, next.js

I am wondering if using firebase admin SDK with next.js 13 server actions is a safe way to save and update data in the database, authenticate users and so. Is it safer than using client SDK and just writing security rules? which one is considered the best pratice?

currently I am using client sdk for user auth and to save data to the database.

Comment: Server Actions are an alpha feature and **not recommended** to be used in production at all. When Server Actions reach production stability they basically behave very similar to API routes and therefore also need to implement the same security concepts.

Comment: @FabioNettis so when server actions become stable it will be safe to use firebase admin SDK inside of them?

Comment: What does "save" mean to you? You will still have to take steps to ensure that your API's are secure. But generally speaking they are as secure as API Routes.